# Changing viewbox values on SVG with bodymovin JSON

Tags: javascript, json, svg, bodymovin

New to dealing with bodymovin. Is there a way to change the viewbox of the exported SVG after parsing it into the browser, either by using Javascript, or by editing the data.json? Basically I want the final output of the viewbox to be "50 0 400 400." I'm able to change the last two values by changing the "w" and "h" properties in the data.json.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the output of the viewBox to be "50 0 400 400" in the generated .js file. Just search for "viewBox" and edit the values.